# Expand Community action in the case feed

Tags: service-cloud-console, casefeed

I have a question regarding the case feed in the console. In a few weeks we will launch our customer community. For that we would like to provide some quick text templates for our engineers to use. Since it's not possible in the regular post we need to use the Community action.

This community action however is very small... 4 visible lines to type a response to the customer. See the picture below (note the action itself is renamed but it is the Community action on the case).

[image]

Is there a way in increase the size of this action?
Would there be another way to use quick text and still make use of the regular post?
Any other options to make this more user friendly and readable?